# Java Swing Cust ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I am trying to make a custom JList, that displays a list of tasks, where each task is represented as follows- type: represented by 3 different icons, status by 2 icons and name as simple String.

My problem is that, at first the custom CellRenderer would not use the appropriate icons for an item in the list until I highlighted the item. Now I changed it a bit and it always uses the same icon (task_small.png) I am sure I am passing in the right data.

Also, if you have advice/criticism on how to improve this code in other ways I will be happy to hear it. I am not sure if using JPanel is the right choice.

```
//imports...

class TaskListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {
    private ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    private JLabel statusAndName = new JLabel();
    private JLabel icon;

      public TaskListCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
      }

      public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
          int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Task entry = (Task) value;

        if (entry.isStatus())
            statusAndName.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("finished.png")));
        else
            statusAndName.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("unfinished.png")));
        statusAndName.setText(entry.getName());

        statusAndName.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));
        int type = entry.getType();
        System.out.println(type);
        if (type == 1)
            icon =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("task_small.png")));
        else if (type == 2)
            icon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("issue_small.png")));
        else if (type == 3)
            icon  = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("request_small.png")));


        //My attempts to make this work- at first I had 3 pre-made Icons which I made icon = to;
        remove(statusAndName);
        remove(icon);
        add(icon, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(statusAndName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        if (isSelected) {
          setBackground(Constants.blue);
          setForeground(Constants.black);
        } else {
          setBackground(Constants.lightGrey);
          setForeground(Constants.black);
        }
        return this;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `statusAndName.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("finished.png")));`  A renderer should not be trying to load resources within the `getListCellRendererComponent` method!  Instead establish those resources as class attributes and load them once in the constructor.  More generally:  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `add(icon, BorderLayout.WEST); add(statusAndName, BorderLayout.CENTER);`  Wait.. what?!?  A renderer should not be adding new components within the rendering method.  That method might be called 100s or thousands of times..

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problems and probably is much more efficient. Thank you everyone!

```
class TaskListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {
    private ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    private JLabel statusAndName = new JLabel();
    private JLabel icon = new JLabel();
    private Icon finishedIcon = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("finished.png"));
    private Icon unfinishedIcon = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("unfinished.png"));
    private Icon taskIcon = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("task_small.png"));
    private Icon requestIcon = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("request_small.png"));
    private Icon issueIcon = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("issue_small.png"));

      public TaskListCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        add(icon, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(statusAndName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }

      public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
          int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Task entry = (Task) value;

        if (entry.isStatus())
            statusAndName.setIcon(finishedIcon);
        else
            statusAndName.setIcon(unfinishedIcon);

        statusAndName.setText(entry.getName());
        statusAndName.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));

        int type = entry.getType();
        System.out.println(type);
        if (type == 1)
            icon.setIcon(taskIcon); 
        else if (type == 2)
            icon.setIcon(issueIcon); 
        else if (type == 3)
            icon.setIcon(requestIcon); 

        if (isSelected) {
          setBackground(Constants.blue);
          setForeground(Constants.black);
        } else {
          setBackground(Constants.lightGrey);
          setForeground(Constants.black);
        }
        return this;
      }
    }
```